Bundling changes made by a script, so that it can be reverted by one undo (ctrl+z)
I've written an Apps Script function that sets values to non-contiguous cells in multiple sheets. This particular function is tied to a custom sheet operation that the user can call from a custom menu tab. As is standard from any sheet operation that a user may do, the user may undo that operation by either clicking the undo icon at the top or hitting ctrl+z. I have written numerous custom functions in Apps Script that perform some sheet operation with those operations being "undoable" with one "undo" click. This is to be expected. In cases where I have not observed this behavior, for example, two undos being required for one sheet operation I have been able to group all of my setvalue() calls together and call SpreadsheetApp.flush() at the end which usually resolves the matter. I'm aware that in Apps Script, Spreadsheet operations are sometimes bundled together to improve performance which can sometimes result in a n:1 ratio of undos to sheet operations to revert a sheet change. This is undesirable because if a user of my sheet makes a change and then realizes that they want to undo that change, they would not be cognizant of the nuances of Apps Script sheet optimization and may incompletely revert a change, resulting in unintended errors. This is what I'm currently experiencing with my sheet
I noticed in testing that more than one undo in google sheets is required to revert the changes made by my script. Specifically, Apps Script is batching out the setValue operations for sheet 1 and sheet2 separately from sheet 3. This means that if I undo, it's a two-step process with the setValue for sheet three being reverted first before sheets 1 and 2. I want only one undo to be required to undo all changes brought on by my script. Calling SpreadsheetApp.flush() at the end does not resolve this issue.
How can I fix this issue so that when the function is called, it can be fully reverted with only one "undo"?
Below is a snippet of code to illustrate the problem.
function load() {
  let toLoad = "Acc1"; 
  
  const sheet1              = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet1");
  const sheet2              = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet2");
  const sheet3              = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet2");
  const sheet1StartRow      = 8;
  const sheet1StartCol      = 14;
  const sheet2StartCol      = 11;
  const sheet3StartCol      = 8;
  const sheet2NumTableCols  = 7;
  const sheet3NumTableCols  = 3;
  const startRow            = 5;
  const sheet1Data1Range    = "L10";
  const sheet1Data2Range    = "I22";
  const sheet1Data3Range    = "I24";
  const sheet1TableRange    = "N8:Q";
  const sheet1TitleRange    = "E8";
  const sheet2Range         = "B5:H";
  const sheet3Range         = "B5:D";
  const numTableRows        = callGetAllAccountVals().length;
  const startBalance        = sheet1.getRange(sheet1Data1Range).getValue();
  const inflows             = sheet1.getRange(commonFields().inflows).getValues(); 
  const sheet1Title         = sheet1.getRange(sheet1TitleRange).getValue();

  let sheet1TableData       = sheet1.getRange(sheet1TableRange).getValues().filter(account => account[0] != "");
  let sheet2RightTableData  = sheet2.getRange(startRow, sheet2StartCol, sheet2.getMaxRows() - startRow + 1, sheet2NumTableCols * numTableRows).getValues();
  let sheet3RightTableData  = sheet3.getRange(startRow, sheet3StartCol, sheet3.getMaxRows() - startRow + 1, sheet3NumTableCols * numTableRows).getValues();

  const sheet2LeftTableData = sheet2.getRange(sheet2Range).getValues();
  const sheet3LeftTableData = sheet3.getRange(sheet3Range).getValues();
  const index2Load          = sheet1TableData.map(row => row[0]).indexOf(toLoad);
  
  const sheet1Data1 = sheet1TableData[index2Load][1];
  const sheet1Data2 = sheet1TableData[index2Load][2];
  const sheet1Data3 = sheet1TableData[index2Load][3];
  const sheet2Data  = sheet2RightTableData.map(row => row.splice(index2Load * sheet2NumTableCols, sheet2NumTableCols));
  const sheet3Data  = sheet3RightTableData.map(row => row.splice(index2Load * sheet3NumTableCols, sheet3NumTableCols));

  sheet1TableData.splice(index2Load, 1); 
  sheet1TableData.push([sheet1Title, startBalance, inflows[0], inflows[2]]);
  for (let i = 0; i < sheet2RightTableData.length; i++) { sheet2RightTableData[i].push(...sheet2LeftTableData[i]); }
  for (let i = 0; i < sheet3RightTableData.length; i++) { sheet3RightTableData[i].push(...sheet3LeftTableData[i]); }

  sheet1.getRange(sheet1TitleRange).setValue(toLoad);
  sheet1.getRange(sheet1Data1Range).setValue(sheet1Data1);
  sheet1.getRange(sheet1Data2Range).setValue(sheet1Data2);
  sheet1.getRange(sheet1Data3Range).setValue(sheet1Data3);
  sheet1.getRange(sheet1StartRow, sheet1StartCol, sheet1TableData.length, sheet1TableData[0].length).setValues(sheet1TableData); 
  sheet2.getRange(sheet2Range).setValues(sheet2Data);
  sheet2.getRange(startRow, sheet2StartCol, sheet2RightTableData.length, sheet2RightTableData[0].length).setValues(sheet2RightTableData);
  sheet3.getRange(sheet3Range).setValues(sheet3Data);
  sheet3.getRange(startRow, sheet3StartCol, sheet3RightTableData.length, sheet3RightTableData[0].length).setValues(sheet3RightTableData);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  
}

Apps Script has an API that enables one to batch out sheet operations. How would this work when the changes are being made across multiple sheets? I'm having trouble parsing the documentation to understand how to begin to set this up.

1) There are roughly 15+ functions assigned to variables for which the code is not included in the question. 2) Please re-read How do I ask a good question? and How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Then edit the question to include all relevant information , sample data and expected outcome(s).

1) The title does not describe the problem. Please edit the title. 2) Please edit the question to describe the circumstances where a user would want/need to "undo" the function. 3) Please describe how the function is triggered.

There are a number of existing questions, comments, discussions and answers regarding "undoing" a function. Have you looked at any of these and would you summarise why your scenario is not addressed by any of these?

You're misunderstanding what I mean by "Undo". The function in the question is a sheet operation that a user can invoke via a custom menu that is created via Apps Script's ui.createMenu() If the user performs this custom operation but for whatever reason wants to undo that operation using google sheet's Undo button (ctrl+z), this gives rise to the problem described in the question. The code that is not included for the multiple functions that are referenced is not relevant here because nowhere in that code are any of the sheets written to. I hope that helps.

I can replace the ambiguous functions with their actual values if it helps to clarify things but I don’t think it’s really germane to the question.

but for whatever reason wants to undo that operation using google sheet's Undo button (ctrl+z) I'm asking - if you never write to a sheet, then 1) why would one want to "undo" a process, and/or 2) why not have a script that "undo's" the original script. With respect, this strikes me an XY problem. But I'll leave you alone and let others contribute.

@Tedinoz I'm not sure I understand your question. The operation itself results in writing data to the sheet. If user of the sheet decided they wanted to undo the operation for whatever reason they would hit ctrl+z or hit undo. But doing this would require them to hit undo more than once which is undesirable behavior.

For "undo" to work as one call for all changes made by a script invocation, You would need to batch all the requests into one Range.setValues() call instead of calling  Range.setValue() multiple times.
If there are multiple subsequent requests to be made, you may try sheets API using advanced Google services to batch all the requests:

Each request is validated before being applied. All subrequests in the batch update are applied atomically. That is, if any request is not valid then the entire update is unsuccessful and none of the (potentially dependent) changes are applied.

It is not possible to batch all the requests, if you need to get data in-between set calls. You have to make all changes in-place without depending on the sheet or spreadsheet functions at all for this to work. Also, it is best practice to batch up operations:

Alternating read and write commands is slow.


And this is possible if you are setting values in non-contiguous cells in different sheets?

@J_code It is possible to set values in non contiguous cells in different sheets using sheets api(or advanced Google services), but I haven't tested undo in particular. You may need to dummy test two set calls as a single batch request and then "undo" to know for sure.
